# Jsforce - jsforce = require('jsforce'); errors out

Tags: node-salesforce

When i install jsforce on my node and add following code the page errors out "application error" what am i doing wrong?

var jsforce = require('jsforce');

am new to node.js and express and jsforce so trying to figure out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. The folder structure was not right and hence it was not able to read library. Its resolved thanks.